# Argument Unpacking wastes Stack Frames

Tags: python, recursion, cpython, python-internals

When a function is called by unpacking arguments, it seems to increase the recursion depth twice. I would like to know *why* this happens.

Normally:

```
depth = 0

def f():
    global depth
    depth += 1
    f()

try:
    f()
except RuntimeError:
    print(depth)

#>>> 999
```

With an unpacking call:

```
depth = 0

def f():
    global depth
    depth += 1
    f(*())

try:
    f()
except RuntimeError:
    print(depth)

#>>> 500
```

In theory both should reach about 1000:

```
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
#>>> 1000
```

This happens on CPython 2.7 and CPython 3.3.

On PyPy 2.7 and PyPy 3.3 there is a difference, but it is much smaller (1480 vs 1395 and 1526 vs 1395).

---

As you can see from the disassembly, there is little difference between the two, other than the type of call (`CALL_FUNCTION` vs `CALL_FUNCTION_VAR`):

```
import dis
```

```
def f():
    f()

dis.dis(f)
#>>>  34           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
#>>>               3 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>               6 POP_TOP
#>>>               7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              10 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
def f():
    f(*())

dis.dis(f)
#>>>  47           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
#>>>               3 BUILD_TUPLE              0
#>>>               6 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR        0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
#>>>               9 POP_TOP
#>>>              10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: By the looks of things, unpacking must call a function, which then calls the target function with unpacked arguments.

Comment: I think @Blckknght was right: building a tuple doesn't seem right, but as Matt points out tuple unpacking is recursive, not so much the construction necessarily.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The exception *message* actually offers you a hint. Compare the non-unpacking option:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(4)  # to get there faster
>>> def f(): f()
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

with:

```
>>> def f(): f(*())
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Note the addition of the `while calling a Python object`. This exception is *specific* to the [`PyObject_CallObject()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject). You won't see this exception when you set an *odd* recursion limit:

```
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(5)
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in f
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

because that is the specific exception raised in the [`ceval.c` frame evaluation code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l1119) inside `PyEval_EvalFrameEx()`:

```c
/* push frame */
if (Py_EnterRecursiveCall(""))
    return NULL;
```

Note the empty message there. This is a crucial difference.

For your 'regular' function (no variable arguments), what happens is that an *optimized path* is picked; a *Python* function that doesn't need tuple or keyword argument unpacking support is handled directly in the [`fast_function()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l4285) of the evaluation loop. A new frameobject with the Python bytecode object for the function is created, and run. This is **one** recursion check.

But for a function call with variable arguments (tuple or dictionary or both), the `fast_function()` call cannot be used. Instead, [`ext_do_call()` (extended call)](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l4463) is used, which handles the argument unpacking, then uses [`PyObject_Call()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l4550) to invoke the function. `PyObject_Call()` does a recursion limit check, and 'calls' the function object. The function object is invoked via the [`function_call()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Objects/funcobject.c#l593), which calls [`PyEval_EvalCodeEx()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l3380), which calls [`PyEval_EvalFrameEx()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a46ebfa5d90/Python/ceval.c#l792), which makes the *second* recursion limit check.

#### TL;DR version

Python functions calling Python functions are optimised and bypass the `PyObject_Call()` C-API function, *unless* argument unpacking takes place. Both Python frame execution and `PyObject_Call()` make recursion limit tests, so bypassing `PyObject_Call()` avoids incrementing the recursion limit check per call.

#### More places with 'extra' recursion depth checks

You can grep the Python source code for `Py_EnterRecursiveCall` for other locations where recursion depth checks are made; various libraries, such as `json` and `pickle` use it to avoid parsing structures that are too deeply nested or recursive, for example. Other checks are placed in the `list` and `tuple` `__repr__` implementations, rich comparisons (`__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__eq__`, etc.), handling the `__call__` callable object hook and handling `__str__` calls.

As such, you can hit the recursion limit *much faster still*:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __str__(self):
...         global depth
...         depth += 1
...         return self()
...     def __call__(self):
...         global depth
...         depth += 1
...         return str(self)
... 
>>> depth = 0
>>> sys.setrecursionlimit(10)
>>> C()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __call__
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __str__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
>>> depth
2
```